# To calculate the distance between point $A = (1,2,3)$ and line $l = (1+t, 1-t, 5+2t)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate the distance between point $A = (1,2,3)$ and line $l = (1+t, 1-t, 5+2t)$.
I'm trying to find a point on the line l that is the closest distance to the point $A$ and then I can use Euclidean distance formula for two points in $3D$. But I'm having trouble finding the point on the line $l$ closest to the point $(1,2,3)$. Is there some formula I should use?

Comment: Get a formula for the (square of the) distance from the point $\ell(t)$ to the point $A$ as a function of $t$ and use calculus to find the $t$ where this value is minimized

Comment: Take a point on a line, draw vector starting at $A$ end ending at that point. Scalar product of that vector and the directional vector of the line should be zero. Find $t$, find the coordinates of that point on the line then find distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any given $t$, the Euclidean distance between the point $(1+t, 1-t, 5+2t)$ on line $l$, and point $A = (1, 2, 3)$, is:

$$d = \sqrt{((1+t) - 1)^2 + ((1-t) - 2)^2 + ((5+2t) - 3)^2}$$

Or equivalently:

$$d = \sqrt{6t^2 + 10t + 5}$$

The distance between $A$ and $l$ is the *minimum* value of $d$.  But since √ is an increasing function, we can just as well minimize $d^2 = 6t^2 + 10t + 5$ .  Setting the derivative of this equal to zero gives:

$$12t + 10 = 0$$
$$t = -\frac{5}{6}$$

Plugging this into the expression for $d$ gives:

$$d = \sqrt{6(-\frac{5}{6})^2 + 10(-\frac{5}{6}) + 5}$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac{25}{6} - \frac{50}{6} + \frac{30}{6}}$$
$$= \sqrt{\frac{5}{6}} \approx 0.912871$$

Answer (score 2):

**Distance of a Point from a Line Given in Component Form**

For the distance $d$ of the point $M = (a, b, c)$ from a line given in the component form, i.e. $\frac{x-x_1}{l}=\frac{y-y_1}{m}=\frac{z-z_1}{n}$, we have:
$$d^2=\frac{\left[(a-x_1)m-(b-y_1)l\right]^2+\left[(b-y_1)n-(c-z_1)m \right]^2+\left[(c-z_1)l-(a-x_1)n\right]^2}{l^2+m^2+n^2}.$$

Comment: (+1) and this results in the same numerical answer as mine.

Comment: To @AnneBauval: Your approach is awesome as well!

Comment: Yours is more helpful, due to its generality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be the closest point to $A$ on the line $l.$ The geometric conditions $H\in l$ and $\overrightarrow{AH}\perp l$ become$$0=1(1+t-1)+(-1)(1-t-2)+2(5+2t-3)$$
$$=t-(-1-t)+2(2+2t)$$
i.e.
$$t=-\frac56,$$
whence (with that value for $t$)
$$d(A,l)=AH=\sqrt{t^2+(-1-t)^2+(2+2t)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{t^2+5(1+t)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac56}.$$

Comment: In your opening equation, instead of factors $1$, $2$, $3$ arising from $A=(1,2,3)$, it should be factors $1$, $-1$, $2$ arising form the direction vector $\langle 1,-1,2\rangle$ of the line $l$.

Comment: Oh, thank you @LeeMosher (I was on my phone, it was uneasy). I correct soon!

Answer (score 0):

Let $l\colon \vec x = \vec a+t\vec u$. Consider the parallelogram spanned by $\vec u$ and $\vec p-\vec a$.  It's height is the distance from $\vec p$ to $l$.

It's area is the length of the cross product of  $(\vec p-\vec a)\times \vec u$.  Now divide by the length of $\vec u$.

We have
$$\vec p-\vec a=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-2
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad
\vec u=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\2
\end{pmatrix},
$$
hence
$$(\vec p-\vec a)\times \vec u=
\begin{pmatrix}0\\-2\\-1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
the area is $\sqrt{5}$ and the length of $\vec u$ is $\sqrt6$, hence the distance equals $\sqrt5/\sqrt6$.